# SVO airport to Bibirevo by public transport

Tags: public-transport, russia, moscow, svo

I am visiting my grandparents in Bibirevo. What is the quickest way to get from SVO to Bibirevo by public transport during the day time (around 2 PM)?

I want to avoid taxis as they can be expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way is to go on the [Aeroexpress train](https://aeroexpress.ru/en/aero/press/news20101411.html) from Sheremetyevo International Airport to Okruzhnaya.

These are the steps:

1. Get the Aeroexpress to Okruzhnaya Rail Terminal
2. Get the 282 bus/take the train and change at Petrovsko-Razumavskaya and take the grey line northbound to Biberevo